# powershell geting email from domain

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to find a way to getting all email sent by *@domain.com.

I'm trying this command

```
Get-MessageTrace -StartDate (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) -EndDate (Get-Date) | where {$_.senderaddress -like "*@ups.com"} | Select Received,*Address,*IP,Subject,Status,Size | ft
```

I don't have any results, and that is not correct because I'm received some mail from *@ups.com in the last few days.

```
Get-MessageTrace -StartDate (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) -EndDate (Get-Date) -SenderAddress pkginfo@ups.com | Select SenderAddress,Status | ft

SenderAddress   Status
-------------   ------
pkginfo@ups.com GettingStatus
pkginfo@ups.com Delivered
pkginfo@ups.com Delivered
pkginfo@ups.com GettingStatus
pkginfo@ups.com Delivered
pkginfo@ups.com Delivered
pkginfo@ups.com Delivered
pkginfo@ups.com Delivered
pkginfo@ups.com Delivered
pkginfo@ups.com Delivered
pkginfo@ups.com Delivered
pkginfo@ups.com Delivered
```

What's wrong in first command?

Answer (score 1):

The Get-MessageTrace command can only go back 10 days.

From the Microsoft documentation: "If you enter a time period that's older than 10 days, you won't receive an error, but the command will return no results. To search for message data that's between 10 and 90 days old, use the Start-HistoricalSearch and Get-HistoricalSearch cmdlets."

Full information here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mail-flow/get-messagetrace?view=exchange-ps